# Gridview Select button no longer works after adding delete button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Ever since I added the Delete button, the Select button no longer redirects to another page when clicked. I added an alert on the OnSelectedIndexChanged and that worked so I am not sure why it no longer redirects. Also, if I remove the delete button the redirect works but I need both buttons.

```
   <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowSelectButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteRecord" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"
                                OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');" />
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

OnSelectedIndexChanged. If I removed **false** it didn't matter either.

```
  protected void listIndexView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx", false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I can't say I seen this behvaour.

But, just drop in two templated buttons and you off to the races so to speak. Because  you NOT REALLY using the built in edit and features of those buttons, then little is to be gained by "half" using the built in buttons that way. So just template two buttons like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="btnSelectD" runat="server" 
        Text="Select" CommandName="Select" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteRecord" runat="server"
             Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"
       OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');" />
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

And as a result, you are free to attach events to each button to do whatever you want.

Note in the code editor, you will see this during editing of the markup and you ARE given a chance to create + add a event stub for buttons inside of that gridview etc.

[image]

Now if the button was outside of the gridview/listview/repeater etc., then you can normally just double click on the button and jump to the codebehind IDE. But when the button is inside of a repeating object, then you can't double click to create + build the event stub, but if you edit in markup as per above, then note how you see that dropdown appear - and you can choose create new event. Choose that, but you THEN have to flip over to code behind - and you will/should see the code stub.